# Why does the battery life of my iPhone last longer when charged with the USB port of my laptop?

Tags: battery

I have an iPhone 12 that's currently at 88% battery capacity. I've noticed that
when I charge it through the USB port of my laptop it lasts way longer than when I charge
it through my charger.

Here's the info on my charger: DC5V / 2.4A Max

I couldn't find the info on my laptops USB port but I assume it's a standard one for a
Lenovo Thinkpad from 2014.

I'd really appreciate an explanation :)

Comment: You need more details than this - What exactly should someone do to experimentally confirm your claim?   No matter how you get to 100%, the battery should discharge the same, so theoretically, I believe you are making some measurement mistake.

Comment: Also, if you are comparing the time to discharge from 100% to 88%, the way that the phone calculates that percentage (which might not be accurate) is important, so it's better to compare the time to discharge from 100% to say 2%.

Comment: See how long it actually lasts by running it down further.  The computer may be charging it slower at 500mA.  There is some resistance between the battery cell and where the shutoff for the charger senses.  The amperage causes a larger voltage difference over this resistance and so 5X current will cause an end to charging with a lower cell voltage. A lot goes into not overcharging (and exploding) a battery so someone could have erred on the side of caution to not start charging again until it falls below some threshold.

Comment: Doesn't this depend upon what you are running.  Do a test where you are running the same app for a period of time.  There must be some iPhone app which shows charge/discharge data.